# unterminated string literal using Feather and aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, aviary

I have an aspx page that i want to launch some javascript once a button is clicked. Like so..

```
  <p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('imgClub', ' <%= imgClub.ImageUrl.ToString()%> ');" /></p>
```

The javascript is below (it is Adobe's Aviary/Feather)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
       apiKey: 'your-key-here',
       apiVersion: 3,
       theme: 'dark', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
       tools: 'all',
       appendTo: '',
       onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
           var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
           img.src = newURL;
       },
       onError: function(errorObj) {
           alert(errorObj.message);
       }
   });
   function launchEditor(id, src) {
       featherEditor.launch({
           image: id,
           url: src
       });
      return false;
   }
</script>
```

The problem is that i'm getting an error at the `<% imgClub.ImageUrl.ToString()%>` on the

```
onclick="return launchEditor('imgClub', ' <%= imgClub.ImageUrl.ToString()%> ');"
```

Comment: ...and what does the error message say?

Comment: So, why are you using a `return` statement outside of a function?

Comment: it is a general 'syntax error' at the second variable position of the launchEditor()

Comment: bc the 'onclick' function of that input tag launchs the `launchEditor()`

Comment: You don't need the `return`. Removing it won't fix the problem, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: So, it's giving you a syntax error on the line that says `featherEditor.launch({` ?